# multiple indexing with slow query

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

In following query I indexed every field like:

- `menu.id`
- `pricelist.menu_id`
- `vendors.id`
- `pricelist.vendor`
- `orders.pricelist_id`
- `pricelist.id`
- `users.id`
- `orders.user_id`
- `orders.free`
- `pricelist.menu_id`.

When I run the below query it takes much time, we have 13 million records in `orders` table and other table has few thousands.

```
SELECT
    `orders`.`itusername`,
    `orders`.`iturl`,
    `orders`.`error_message`,
    `orders`.`return` AS return1,
    `orders`.`coupon`,
    DATEDIFF( users.reseller_expiry, now( ) ) AS edays,
    `users`.`email`,
    `menu`.`menuname`,
    `orders`.`error_status`,
    `orders`.`auto_status`,
    `vendors`.`name`,
    `vendors`.`id` AS venderid,
    `pricelist`.`servicename`,
    `orders`.`email_order` AS paypal_order_email,
    `orders`.`user_id`,
    `orders`.`services_order`,
    `orders`.`created_dt`,
    `orders`.`id`,
    `orders`.`transaction_comment`,
    `orders`.`url`,
    `orders`.`requireviews`,
    `orders`.`youtubeviews`,
    `orders`.`total_views_completed`,
    `orders`.`aff`,
    `orders`.`is_package`,
    `orders`.`price`,
    `orders`.`order_from_site`,
    `orders`.`cost_per_unit_order`,
    `orders`.`service_name_order`,
    `orders`.`status`,
    `orders`.`start_api_date`,
    `orders`.`end_api_date`,
    `orders`.`allow_setting`,
    `orders`.`return2`,
    `users`.`balance` AS user_balance 
FROM
    ( `pricelist` )
    JOIN `menu` ON `menu`.`id` = `pricelist`.`menu_id`
    JOIN `vendors` ON `vendors`.`id` = `pricelist`.`vendor`
    JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`pricelist_id` = `pricelist`.`id`
    JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` 
WHERE
    `orders`.`free` != 1 
    AND pricelist.menu_id = 3 
ORDER BY
    `orders`.`id` DESC 
    LIMIT 10.
```

.................................

Comment: No. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Further, in addition to SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: **below is the explain query ,it the screenshot**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zWot.png

Comment: Perhaps you failed to read the linked answer. Well, we're in no rush

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to do the `LIMIT` *before* running around to 5 tables.

```
SELECT  ...
    FROM 
        ( SELECT  orders.pricelist_id AS id
            FROM  pricelist
            JOIN  `orders`  ON `orders`.`pricelist_id` = `pricelist`.`id`
            WHERE  `orders`.`free` != 1
              AND  pricelist.menu_id = 3
            ORDER BY  `orders`.`id` DESC
            LIMIT  10 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  `pricelist`  ON pricelist.id = x.id
    JOIN  `menu`       ON `menu`.`id` = `pricelist`.`menu_id`
    JOIN  `vendors`    ON `vendors`.`id` = `pricelist`.`vendor`
    JOIN  `orders`     ON `orders`.`pricelist_id` = x.`id`
    JOIN  `users`      ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` 
    ORDER BY  `orders`.`id` DESC
```

There is a unknown -- are the tables 1:1 or 1:many or many:1 or many:many?  With the 'wrong' answers, you will get more than 10 rows, and the design is flawed.